# zipWith for trees in Haskell

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

I am learning Haskell using The Haskell School of Expression: Learning Functional Programming through Multimedia and I am unsure how to go about solving this exercise.

> Using the definition of trees given by
>
> ```
> data Tree a = Node (Tree a) (Tree a) | Leaf a
> ```
>
> Define tree versions of the list functions `zip` and `zipWith`. There
>   will be cases at the leaves or where trees are of different shapes
>   where you’ll have to make design decisions. Try to make your decisions
>   as elegant as possible.

For `zip` I have this but I am unsure if it is "elegant"

```haskell
zipTree :: Tree a -> Tree b -> Tree (a,b)
zipTree (Leaf a)     (Leaf b)     = Leaf (a,b)
zipTree (Node l1 r1) (Node l2 r2) = 
  let l = zipTree l1 l2
      r = zipTree r1 r2 
  in Node l r 

-- Problems...
zipTree (Node _ _)  (Leaf _)   = Node undefined undefined
zipTree (Leaf _)    (Node _ _) = Node undefined undefined
```

And I am unsure how to adapt it to have `zipWith` functionality although I do know a elegant definition of zipWith.

```haskell
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWith f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : zipWith f xs ys
zipWith _ _ _ = []
```

Comment: Note that you only really have to define `zipTreeWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> (Tree a) -> (Tree b) -> (Tree c)`, since `zipTree` is then just the special case `zipWith = zipTreeWith (,)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all I believe your solution is not elegant because you are using `undefined`.
You want to avoid partial functions, and structures, as much as possible and simply inserting some `Node undefined undefined` in a tree structure doesn't sound like a good idea.

Think about this: once you have a `Node undefined undefined` how would it act with the other operations on the tree? You'd probably get tons of exceptions.

So you have to find an alternative.

```
zipTree (Node l r) (Leaf a) = Node x y
    where
        x = ... ? 
        y = ... ?
```

Now how should `x` and `y` be defined? `x` should depend on `l` and `Leaf a` while `y` should depend on `r` and `Leaf a`.

The easiest way to define this case is to simply perform the recursive calls:

```
zipTree (Node l r) a@(Leaf _) = Node (zipTree l a) (zipTree r a)
```

So we are zipping all leafs in the `l` and `r` subtrees with the leaf `a`.

As for the `zipWithTree`: that's easy. You have to add an `f` parameter and use `f x y` instead of `(x, y)` when you perform the zipping, which is done only in the `Leaf` v `Leaf` case:

```
zipWithTree f (Leaf a) (Leaf b) = Leaf $ f a b
```

Obviously you have to add the `f` parameter to all the rules and pass `f` to recursive calls.

---

Note that there is also an other way to define `zipWith`, which is:

```
zipTree (Node _ _) (Leaf a) = Leaf (undefined, a)
```

This still isn't a good solution because it introduces an `undefined` however it has some advantages against the `Node undefined undefined` solution:

1. It acts for similarly to `zip` from lists. `zip [1,2] [1,2,3,4] == [(1,1), (2,2)]` so you stop when the shorter list ends.
2. The `undefined` is *inside* the value. This allows for example to have:

   ```
   mapTree snd (zipTree x y) == y
   ```

   whenever `x` has longer branches. Using `Node undefined undefined` you have `mapTree f (zipTree x y)` is *always* an exception whenever the trees aren't isomorphic (because `mapTree` will try to evaluate `undefined`).