# Haskell: Defining Trees using zip/zipWith

Tags: haskell, tree

I am really new with Haskell and I decided to play around with `Tree`s using the `zip` function. I was able to find this code from a website but I am not sure what input should I use. It would be really helpful if someone explained/help me with this.

```
data Tree a = Node (Tree a) (Tree a) | Leaf a

zip (Leaf a) (Leaf b) = Leaf (a,b)
zip (Leaf a) (Node l r) = Leaf (a,a)
zip (Node l r) (Leaf b) = Leaf (b,b)
zip (Node l1 r1) (Node l2 r2) = Node (zip l1 r1) (zip l2 r2)
```

Comment: Try adding a `deriving Show` to the end of the `data` declaration. Then you can pull up GHCi, run `zip (Node (Leaf 1) (Leaf 2)) (Node (Leaf 3) (Leaf 4))`, and look at the output.

Comment: is it only me or is this `zip` a bit strange?

Comment: wouldn't you expect that `zip (Node (Leaf 'a') (Leaf 'b')) (Node (Leaf 3) (Leaf 4))` works and produces `Node (Leaf ('a',3)) (Leaf ('b',4))`?

Comment: I believe you should have `zip :: Tree a -> Tree b -> Tree (a,b)`. Try to add the type signature to your function and you'll see that it is incorrect. Your function has type `Tree a -> Tree a -> Tree (a,a)`.   You are probably following the same tutorial/course as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36398709/510937).

Comment: @haoformayor I tried doing that and yes it did work thank you. I got an output of 

        Node (Leaf (1,2)) (Leaf (3,4))

Comment: @Bakuriu maybe we should mark this as an duplicate - this question is both better stated and has a great answer already